# Dialog style not applying

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app i want my dialog to be a curved rectangle,so for that i have created a custom style for dialog in my app.The rectangle comes properly but there is also black rectangle behind which i dont want.How to hide that
[image]

Style.Xml

```
<style name="dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">

        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>


    </style>
```

Curved Rectangle.Xml

```
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#2196F3" />
    <corners android:radius="100px" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#fff" />




</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme

```
<style name="ThemeDialogCustom">
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Where should i set my drawable i.e. the curved rectangle?

Comment: @Anuj No use as is. Use this as a style only. Set your curved rectangle as background of your layout file.

Comment: Tried as u said, but still no success

Answer (score 0):

You can apply custom theme to Dialog while initializing like

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```